# AngularJS : ngRepeat with isolated scope directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with AngularJS, I have created a directive which has isolated scope. Directive is working fine without inside ngRepeat. When I use directive inside ngRepeat it creates its siblings and I went into a state where I have to iterate throw $$childSiblings.

Now question is

1. Should I use isolated scope directives inside ngRepeat?
2. Does angular do this with all directive or I have implemented a wrong directive (I mean should I use isolated scope or not?
3. How to access N-th direcive scope when used in ngRepeat? I mean I have 10 directives which are created by `ng-repeat` and I want to access 5th directive?

Here is the HTML layout snippet I am wondering about

**User A**

```
Role A
Role B
Role C
Role D
Role Z
```

**User B**

```
Role A
Role B
Role C
Role D
Role Z
```

**User C**

```
Role A
Role B
Role C
Role D
Role Z
```

Here Role A,B,C..Z are directives having there own scope but with ngRepeat they are creating their scope in $$childSiblings

Comment: can you please provide some code and more importantly explain what **and why** you're trying to do this?

Comment: Robert Koritnik I have a scenario where a user can belong to many roles. screen enlists all users with their associated roles so screen looks like User A
 Role A
 Role B
 Role C
 Role D
 Role Z
 
User B
 Role A
 Role B
 Role C
 Role D
 Role Z
 
User C
 Role A
 Role B
 Role C
 Role D
 Role Z
 here Role is the directive I am talking about and User is the parent directive inside ngRepeat and Role directive is also inside ngRepeat

Comment: @UmerHayat: Kindly provide some code here. so that folks can understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Two things: **1:** Can you also add code of your directive? and **2:** You still haven't explained your process why you need to check those siblings? Because usually in AngularJS you should be working with your model and not work with data in view/directive... At least by understanding your process we may suggest better approach.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I understand that User should be a directive that contains an ng-repeat that creates a new role directive in each iteration. Usually is a good practice to create an isolate scope directive because then you don't rely in external code. Helps to maintain you directive isolate